# i am trying to convert .jsp to .pdf format using pd4ml. when start executing my code i am getting execption below

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        PdfViewerStarter jt = new PdfViewerStarter();
        jt.doConversion("http://pd4ml.com/sample.htm", "D:/pd4ml.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void doConversion(String url, String outputPath)
    throws InvalidParameterException, MalformedURLException, IOException {
    File output = new File(outputPath);
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(output);

    PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();
    pd4ml.setHtmlWidth(userSpaceWidth);
    pd4ml.setPageSize(pd4ml.changePageOrientation(PD4Constants.A4));
    pd4ml.setPageInsetsMM(new Insets(topValue, leftValue, bottomValue, rightValue));
    pd4ml.useTTF("c:/windows/fonts", true);
    pd4ml.render(new URL(url), fos);
    fos.close();

    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(output);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Awt Desktop is not supported!");
    }

    System.out.println(outputPath + "\ndone.");
}
```

Error:

Error. ss_css2.jar is not in the classpath. See README.txt

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/css/sac/CSSException

```
          at org.zefer.html.doc.PD4MLHtmlParser.o00000(Unknown Source)

          at org.zefer.html.doc.PD4MLHtmlParser.<init>(Unknown Source)

          at org.zefer.pd4ml.PD4ML.super(Unknown Source)

          at org.zefer.pd4ml.PD4ML.render(Unknown Source)

          at TestForPdfPD4ML.doConversion(TestForPdfPD4ML.java:42)

          at TestForPdfPD4ML.main(TestForPdfPD4ML.java:24)
```

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.w3c.css.sac.CSSException

```
          at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)

          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)

          at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)

          at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)

          ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be asking for the ClassPath of the Jar File where the needed (imported) libraries are contained. If you are running from Command Line try something like this:
java -cp .;"The full path where the Jar File is\jarfile.jar" YourRunningClassFile